# gcc compiled program on SUSE Linux doesn't required ld.so.cache update?

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries

This is my system:

```
# cat /etc/SuSE-release
openSUSE 11.4 (i586)
VERSION = 11.4
CODENAME = Celadon
# uname -r
2.6.37.1-1.2-default
# gcc --version
gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.5.1 20101208 [gcc-4_5-branch revision 167585]
...
```

Now I have these files:

foo.h:

```
void foo();
```

foo.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void foo(){
    printf("Hello World\n");
}
```

main.c:

```
#include <foo.h>
int main(){
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

...and I do the following:

```
# gcc -c -fpic foo.c
# gcc -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o
```

I then copy `foo.h` to `/usr/include` and `libfoo.so` to `/lib`, (note that there is no ldconfig run) then compile with:

```
# gcc -o test main.c -l foo
```

### The problem:

Without running `ldconfig`, meaning `ld.so.cache` doesn't have `libfoo.so`. Yet, `# ./test` ran just fine (!?). Somehow `ld` is aware and auto-loads my lib. This is the output of `ldd`:

```
# ldd test
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xffffe000)
libfoo.so => /lib/libfoo.so (0xb77d1000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xb7668000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb77e1000)
```

I've looked around and already crossed out the possibility that `RPATH` is at work here. (Running `readelf -d test` yields no `RPATH`. EDIT: Also, those environment variables you see in `ld.so` man page (like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) is not set.

Why is this happening? An interesting note is that on a Red Hat system (CentOS 6), everything ran as expected (I have to do a `ldconfig` to reload the cache)

Answer (score 1):

The [Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig) on ldconfig is unclear as to the real intention of the cache, so I quote the [BSD manpage](http://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/8/ldconfig/) (emphasis mine):

> The ldconfig utility is used to prepare a set of "hints" for use by the dynamic linker **to facilitate quick lookup of shared libraries available in multiple directories**. It scans a set of built-in system directories and any directories specified on the command line (in the given order) looking for shared libraries and stores the results in a system file to forestall the overhead that would otherwise result from the directory search operations the dynamic linker would have to perform to load the required shared libraries.

It is not required to run ldconfig. It is only supposed to speed things up. The runtime linker knows it needs to look in `/usr/lib`, but it will actually only do this after it can't locate the lib in its cache.

Comment: I'm currently not owning any BSD system, so I can't check for sure, but on Red Hat system, missing libraries on the cache (even when the lib is still in `/lib` or `/usr/lib`) will still results in lib not found. Furthermore, I have tried this on another binary on the same SuSE system (the `libz` lib of the binary `/usr/bin/ssh`, and the behavior is as expected (need to reload cache everytime something's added).